# Path integral in the complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

> Evaluate $\int_Tz\,\mathrm dz$ and $\int_T\overline z\,\mathrm dz$ where $T$ is the triangle with vertices $0,1,-i$ oriented clockwise.

I am trying to solve this question, but I'm unsure how to parameterize it. Can you explain how I get this to an integrable form?

Answer (score 0):

From $0$ to $1:$ $$\gamma(t)=t, t\in [0,1].$$

From $1$ to $-i:$ $$\gamma(t)=1-t-it, t\in [0,1].$$

From $-i$ to $0:$ $$\gamma(t)=(t-1)i, t\in [0,1].$$

Thus,

$$\int_T zdz=\int_0^1 tdt+\int_0^1 (1-t-it)(-1-i)dt+\int_0^1(t-1)iidt\\=\left[\frac{t^2}{2}\right]_0^1-(1+i)\left[t-\frac{t^2}{2}-i\frac{t^2}{2}\right]_0^1 -\left[\frac{t^2}{2}-t\right]_0^1 \\=\frac12-(1+i)\left(\frac12-i\frac12\right)+\frac12=0.$$

Comment: $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt.$

Comment: what would f(γ(t)) be when γ(t)=1-t-it?

Comment: If $f(z)=z$ then $f(\gamma(t))=\gamma(t)=1-t-it.$ If $f(z)=\overline{z}$ then $f(\gamma(t))=\overline{\gamma(t)}=\overline{1-t-it}=1-t+it.$

Comment: even though z=x+iy?

Comment: could you say that it is equal to zero as f is holomorphic on a simply connected domain and the path is a closed smooth curve within A?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ is holomorphic on some simply connected region then the integral of $f$ along any closed curve contained in the region if zero.